# Extend template conditionally in Twig

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

Take the following tree structure:

```
├───base
│   ├───0001
│   │   └───pages
│   │           file.twig
│   │           file_content.twig
│   └───ext
│       └───store
│       │   └───pages
│       │       └───all
│       │       │       file.twig
│       │       └───0001
│       │               file.twig
│       └───newsletter
│           └───pages
│               └───all
│               │       file.twig
│               └───0001
│                       file.twig
└───pages
    │   file.twig
    └───0001
            file.twig
```

As you can see, there's a load of `file.twig` scattered around.

I want to render the contents of the file `base/0001/pages/file_content.twig`.
But, I want that the following files can change the content inside blocks:

- `ext/<...>/pages/0001/file.twig`
- `ext/<...>/pages/all/file.twig`
- `/pages/0001/file.twig`
- `/pages/file.twig`

But, these files may or may not exist, may or may not be needed and must be able to change the content of any block.

Is there any way to make this work?

So far, I have the following:

```
{% embed 'base/pages/file_content.twig' %}
    {% block page_file %}
        {{ parent() }}
        {% if data.store_enabled %}
            {% include [
                    'base/ext/store/pages/0001/file.twig',
                    'base/ext/store/pages/all/file.twig'
                ] ignore missing
            %}
        {% endif %}
        {% include ['pages/0001/file.twig', 'pages/file.twig'] ignore missing %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

This "works", in the sense that it renders the page but doesn't allow any block to be overrided.

How could I make this work?

---

As an example, consider this structure of files (yes, files are missing, and that's expected):

```
    ├───base
    │   ├───0001
    │   │   └───pages
    │   │           file.twig
    │   │           file_content.twig
    │   └───ext
    │       └───store
    │       │   └───pages
    │       │       └───0001
    │       │               file.twig
    └───pages
            file.twig
```

The file `base/0001/pages/file_content.twig` has the following:

```
{% block page_file %}
    {% block title %}<h1>Nice title</h1>{% endblock %}
    {% block price %}{% endblock %}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

The file `base/ext/store/pages/0001/file.twig` has the following content:

```
{% block price %}<span class="price">55 &euro;</span>{% endblock %}
```

And the file `pages/file.twig` has:

```
{% block title %}{{ parent() }}<hr>{% endblock %}
{% block price %}<div>{{ parent() }}</div>{% endblock %}
```

The output I expect is the following:

```
<h1>Nice title</h1><hr>
<div><span class="price">55 &euro;</span</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

But with that code, all the other files' changes are being ignored and the output is being only the following:

```
<h1>Nice title</h1>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

---

**Note:**

It's important to notice that I'm using Twig 1.33.2, and using the `Twig_Autoloader::register();` method.

I can't use Twig 2.x, since it requires PHP 7.0+ and I'm restricted to PHP 5.3.29.

Comment: `ignore missing` is also available for the embed node

Comment: @DarkBee But you can only embed 1 file, and `use` doesn't allow any `ignore missing`

Comment: What do you mean with include only one embed? The current setup will include the first found template and display it? If you mean place an embed inside an embed, than this is possible see [here](https://twigfiddle.com/y9q0yp)

Comment: @DarkBee Let me try that

Comment: @DarkBee I'm having a really hard time to wrap my head around how I could use it. But, I think an example should help?

Comment: @DarkBee I've added an example of what I expect to happen. If it is confusing, I can explain better.

Comment: I see. Included / embedded files can't alter the blocks of their includer in Twig. That's the problem

Comment: @DarkBee I know, but an embed file or extending the file allows to change it's blocks. I know that because I can do `{% block bla %} [...] {% endblock %}` inside the `{% embed ... %}` and it works. I'm trying my hardest to think of a solution, given the weird requirements I have.

Comment: @DarkBee I've actually got **very** close to what I want, but there's an annoying `use` that stubburnly ignored the conditions. You can play with it on https://twigfiddle.com/f32bw1

Comment: The closest i'm getting you is [this](https://twigfiddle.com/f32bw1/2)

Comment: That is so close, but I can't assume the contents of anything, except the `base/0001/pages/file_content.twig`. And then, I can assume a few blocks, which should work well with what you show.

Comment: @DarkBee I've found a solution and added it as an answer. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more attempts, I've finally figured a way to do this.

This is as ugly as it may seem...

Assuming the structure:

```
├───base
│   ├───0001
│   │   └───pages
│   │           file.twig
│   │           file_content.twig
│   └───ext
│       └───store
│       │   └───pages
│       │       └───0001
│       │               file.twig
└───pages
        file.twig
```

The main file (`base/pages/file.twig`) has the following code:

```
{% if data.store_enabled %}
    {% include [
            'base/ext/store/pages/0001/file.twig',
            'base/ext/store/pages/all/file.twig',

            'base/pages/file_content.twig'
        ] ignore missing
    %}
{% else %}
    {% include [
            'pages/0001/file.twig',
            'pages/file.twig',

            'base/pages/file_content.twig'
        ] ignore missing
    %}
{% endif %}
```

This will include the files inside `base/ext/store/pages/` if they exist. If a file is missing there, then the file `base/pages/file_content.twig` is included.

All the files inside `base/ext/store/pages/` must have the following code on the top:

```
{% extends [
        'pages/0001/file.twig',
        'pages/file.twig',

        'base/pages/file_content.twig'
    ]
%}
```

And the files inside `pages/` must have the following:

```
{% extends 'base/pages/file_content.twig' %}
```

This allows you to have override **any** block inside `base/pages/file_content.twig` and the files are only included/extended if they exist.

Having there a garanteed file (in this case, `base/pages/file_content.twig` **must** always exist) will still display the "default" content and won't throw a nasty exception.

---

Outside of the scope of this answer, I've initially found a very similar aproach, which used conditional values.

Try it on: https://twigfiddle.com/u06tur